# Hamiltonian-Jacobi-Bellman Equation for Mayer Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, hamilton-jacobi-equation

All papers I have read define the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation starting from the Bolza Problem like so:

$$\min_u J=\phi(x(t_f))+\int_{t_0}^{t_f} L(x(t),u(t),t)dt$$

subjected to

$$ \frac{dx(t)}{dt} = f(x(t),u(t),t), \quad x(t_0)=x_0. $$

The value function can then be defined as

$$ V(t,x(t))=\min_u \int_t^{t_f} L(x(\tau),u(\tau),\tau)d\tau + \phi(x(t_f)).$$

The HJB is then

$$ -\frac{\partial V(t,x)}{\partial t} = \min_u (L(x,u,t) + \frac{\partial V(t,x)}{\partial x} f(x,u,t))$$

where

$$ V(t_f,x(t_f)) = \phi(x(t_f)).$$

My question is what is the HJB when $L(x,u,t)= 0$ (i.e., the Mayer problem)? It seems obvious that the HJB should be

$$ 0 = \min_u (\frac{\partial V(t,x)}{\partial x} f(x,u,t)).$$

$\frac{\partial V(t,x)}{\partial t}$ is set to zero because $V(t,x(t))=\phi(x(t_f))$ which is time independent. For the Mayer problem, $\frac{\partial V(t,x)}{\partial x} f(x,u,t)$ is effectively the Hamiltonian, which is only equal to 0 throughout the time domain if the final time is optimal. Thus, if the predefined $t_f$ is not optimal, then the HJB I proposed for the Mayer problem should be incorrect (I believe)? Can anyone define the HJB for the Mayer problem, or point me in the direction to a resource that does?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your assessment that $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$ is zero for the Mayer problem. Imagine your boss asks you to be at the office at 8:00, i.e. you'll get a hefty $\phi$ if $x(t_f=\text{8:00})$ isn't the office. Would you expect $V(t=\text{7:58}, x=\text{home})$ to be equal to $V(t=\text{7:00}, x=\text{home})$, considering that the traffic dynamic $f$ means you take about an hour to get to the office? I think $V(t=\text{7:58}, x=\text{home})$ would be much larger since you'll certainly be late.

Comment: I think the HJB for the Mayer problem would just be that of the Bolza problem with $L(x,u,t) = 0$, no further general simplifications. I think that in the Mayer case, it is (as far as I can imagine) impossible for $V$ to be time-invariant, because $t_f$ is a specific finite time. The common case of time-invariant $V$ is for Bolza problems with $t_f \to \infty$ and $\phi = 0$.

Comment: @jnez71 I believe you are likely right. My time invariant assumption is probably wrong. However, with $L=0$, that would mean $V(t,x(t)) = \phi(x(t_f=known value))$. I'm confused how this equation is not constant for all time. Is this value function incorrect?

Comment: The arguments of $V$ are really $t_0$ and $x_0$. I assumed that's what you had meant in your post but it seems that may be the source of your confusion. For all intents and purposes, $t$ and $x(t)$ are just intermediates in the calculation of $J$. The actual arguments of $J$ are the function $u$ and the initial condition $x_0$ at $t_0$. Then $V$ just functionally minimizes-out $u$. So for your Mayer problem it's, $$V(t_0, x_0) = \min_u \Big{[}\phi\big{(}x(t_f)\big{)}\ \Big{\vert}\ \dot{x}(t)=f\big{(}x(t),u(t)\big{)},\, x(t_0) = x_0\Big{]}$$

Comment: @ jnez71 Thankyou, this very helpful. I'm going to try to pick your brain one more time. Lets say I have all the data pertaining to an optimal trajectory. I have $x(t)$ and $u(t)$ for all $t\in[0,1,2,3,\dots t_f]$. Also, $\phi(x(t_f)) = -x(t_f)$. How would I go about calculating V(t_0,x_0) for every moment in discretized time pertaining to my data? Would V(t_0,x_0) simply be $-x(t_f)$?I believe it should not, only $V(t_0=t_f,x_0 = x_f) = -x_f$?

Comment: The equation $V(t_0=t_f, x_0=x) = \phi(x)\, \ \forall x$ is correct, and is considered the temporal boundary condition on $V$. In other words, at time $t_f$, $V$ is $\phi$. However, $V$ is not constant in general. To compute it for all other $t_0 < t_f$, you have to solve the Bellman equation backwards in time. Depending on the dynamic, state space, and other details of the problem, this can be very easy or insanely hard to do. The solution does not care about any particular "open-loop" optimal trajectory you might already know.

Comment: If you feel I have answered your question, let me know so I can put it into an acceptable answer format.